# Not able to interact with application using any of the locator - throwing me 'Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session'

Tags: appium, appium-android

Testing an Android app and not able interact with app

Tried with ID, xpath and other locator but still display same error message.

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.Button[@text='English']")
public WebElement language;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.Button[@text='GET STARTED']")
public WebElement start;
```

The error I am getting is:

> FAILED: login org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session For documentation on this error, please visit: seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'nsubramani-mbp-1', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10b4:b83f:ee48:38b2%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_202' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

Comment: post the error message ...

Comment: I'm using appium version - v1.13.0

Comment: FAILED: login
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Locator Strategy 'name' is not supported for this session
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'nsubramani-mbp-1', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:10b4:b83f:ee48:38b2%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

Comment: Add error from comments

Comment: [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\"sessionId\":\"007df5ef-7d23-4ae1-a8fa-98c92c74e13a\",\"status\":0,\"value\":\"Session deleted\"}"
[ADB] Running '/Users/nsubramani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop in.okcredit.merchant'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8201 
[ADB] Running '/Users/nsubramani/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 forward --remove tcp\:8201'
[Instrumentation] .
[Instrumentation] Time: 19.127
[Instrumentation]